# PDFBox 2.0.11 - slow generate PDF after adding external font

Tags: pdfbox

I have a problem with PDF generate performance, after adding and using external font. The way how I do it, is standard(that's why I will not put full code):

I load font by:

```
PDType0Font.load(new PDDocument(), fontInputStream, false)
```

Then for each acroForm I set this font by:

```
PDResources defaultResources = acroForm.getDefaultResources();
COSName fontCOSName = defaultResources.add(font);
```

Does anyone had similar problem or know how can I resolve it?

Comment: `PDType0Font.load(new PDDocument(), …` is wrong and not "standard". Use your existing document object, don't create a new one. However I don't know if this is the cause of your alleged slowness. You should provide some code that actually runs, and then tell what you expected to happen.

Comment: If you want to reuse a font for several documents, use `load(PDDocument doc, TrueTypeFont ttf, boolean embedSubset)`. `TrueTypeFont ttf = new TTFParser().parse(….);`

Comment: Thanks, I made corrections, but still I have problem with performance. Maybe later I will be able to provide more code, how about method:
acroField.getAcroForm().getDefaultResources().getResourceCache() 
Do You know if this can be useful?

Comment: That cache is to speed up rendering / extraction. It won't help you when ccreating PDFs.